# Expo Auth Session Two Factor Browser dismiss

Tags: android, expo, google-authentication

- Expo Bare Workflow App
- SDK Version: 44
- Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

Hi, this is my first topic here so if it’s missing something, please let me know!

I have a problem when trying to login with a Google account that has two factor authentication enabled and the authorization phone is the same one I’m using to login.

From what I understood, what happens is that the browser the `expo-auth-session` opens asking my Google Credentials closes when the Google Authorization app screen shows over the my Expo app, because it always return the `dismiss` status.

Is there a way to prevent the browser from closing if another app opens over it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm encountering the same issue